# Can someone explain what this bit of code does?

Tags: haskell

I know it involves some recursion over a list but I'm struggling  with what its adding to the lists and what x22,k and t represents.

```
insertM :: Message -> [(Name, Int)] -> [(Name, Int)]
insertM (M x1 x2 m) [] = [(x2, 1)] 
insertM (M x1 x2 m) ((x22,k):t) = do
    if x2 == x22 then 
        (x22, k+1):t
    else do
        (x22, k): insertM (M x1 x2 m) t
```

This might help

```
data Message = M Name Name String deriving (Show)
```

Comment: Here a list `[(Name, Int)]` is used as a counter to count the amount of times a `Name` occurs as second item by a message: the counter is here updated with one for the name of the given `Message`.

Comment: The `do` does nothing useful and should be omitted.

Comment: This code is...  really sketchy. A list of pairs is an inefficient data type for this. The `do` block is weird and unnecessary. It should be using guards instead of `if`. And there's a convention for what ending a function name with M means which doesn't apply to this function.

Comment: The code essentially searches for the first pair of the form `(x2, counter)` in the list, and increments its related counter. If there's no such pair, a new pair `(x2,1)` is appended at the very end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function inserts Messages in a List of Messages. And if the Message already is in the list increases the Message counter.

So line by line:

```
insertM (M x1 x2 m) [] = [(x2, 1)]
```

If the List is `empty` and you insert a Message, just enter the message with count 1.

```
insertM (M x1 x2 m) ((x22,k):t) = do
```

Thats the second case (look up pattern matching if you don't understand), where you insert a message, which looks like this `(M x1 x2 m)` into a list with the header `(x22,k)` and a tail `t`.

```
if x2 == x22 then 
    (x22, k+1):t
```

This lines checks if the part of the message `x2`is the same as the `x22` of the first element of the list and the increments the counter. If this isn't the case you look up the rest of the list

```
  (x22, k): insertM (M x1 x2 m) t
```

`(x22,k)` is the head of the list, `:` appends two lists, `insertM (M x1 x2 m) t` is a recursive call on the tail where you lookup the rest of the list.

For example:

```
(insertM (M "A" "B" "chicken") [])         => [("B",1)]
(insertM (M "A" "B" "chicken") [("B",1)])  => [("B",2)]
(insertM (M "A" "C" "chicken") [("B",2)])  => [("B",2),("C",1)]
```

Any further questions?